# Problems with program, wont download file to the proper directory in Linux

Tags: java, swing, minecraft

So, I been working on a few things, one of which is a general game launcher, Basically it downloads games that I have created or it downloads mods for an already existing game, like minecraft. On a linux system minecraft is located at: root/home//.minecraft For some reason, nomatter how many times I rewrite how this program downloads things it refuses to put it into the .minecraft directory. When downloaded all it does is create a ZIP file with the name as root home/naiakoa/.minecraft/toxicnaga.zip in the root directory (Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6kp7.jpg) At this point I really have no clue what to do to correct this issue.

```
   //Button to Install mods
    b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (OSver.startsWith("Windows"))
            {
                try{
                    one.mkdir();
                    two.mkdir();
                    three.mkdir();

                    System.out.println("Downloading \'Installing ToxicNaga modpack\'...");
                    saveFileFromUrlWithJavaIO(dirName + "\\TestZip.zip", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47132467/Test%20Zip.zip");
                    unzip(dirName + "\\TestZip.zip", dirName);


                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(html1 + "450" + html2 + SelfDo));

                }catch(Exception zip){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, zip.getMessage()+""+OSver);}
            }
            else if(OSver.startsWith("Linux"))
            {
                try{
                    String UserInfo = txt1.getText().toLowerCase();

                    String dirLinuxName = System.getProperty("user.home")+ "\\home\\" + UserInfo + "\\.minecraft\\";

                    System.out.println("Downloading \'Minecraft pack Linux edition\'...");
                    saveFileFromUrlWithJavaIO(dirLinuxName + "TestZip.zip", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47132467/Test%20Zip.zip");
                    unzip(dirLinuxName + "TestZip.zip", dirLinuxName);

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(html1 + "450" + html2 + SelfDo));
                }catch (Exception linux){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, linux.getMessage() + " " + OSver);}
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(html1 + "450" + html2 + " "+OSver+""+dirLinuxName));
            }
            else
            {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JLabel(html1 + "450" + html2 + "Currently your Operating system is not supported. Please contact Naiakoa Unila for direct report of your operating system and the version of it that is running. And please give it time for the launcher to be updated to support your operating system."+OSver));
            }
        }
    });
    //Download Controller
public static void saveFileFromUrlWithJavaIO(String fileName, String fileUrl)
        throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    BufferedInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream fout = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(fileUrl).openStream());
        fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

        byte data[] = new byte[5024];
        int count;
        while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 5024)) != -1) {
            fout.write(data, 0, count);
        }
    } finally {
        if (in != null)
            in.close();
        if (fout != null)
            fout.close();
    }
}
//Unzip Controller
public static void unzip(String zipFile,String outputPath){

    if(outputPath == null)
        outputPath = "";
    else
        outputPath+=File.separator;

    // 1.0 Create output directory
    File outputDirectory = new File(outputPath);

    if(outputDirectory.exists())
        outputDirectory.delete();

    outputDirectory.mkdir();

    // 2.0 Unzip (create folders & copy files)
    try {

        // 2.1 Get zip input stream
        ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile));

        ZipEntry entry = null;
        int len;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5024];

        // 2.2 Go over each entry "file/folder" in zip file
        while((entry = zip.getNextEntry()) != null){

            if(!entry.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println("-"+entry.getName());

                // create a new file
                File file = new File(outputPath +entry.getName());

                // create file parent directory if does not exist
                if(!new File(file.getParent()).exists())
                    new File(file.getParent()).mkdirs();

                // get new file output stream
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                // copy bytes
                while ((len = zip.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                fos.close();
            }

        }

    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Linux uses forward slashes for directories, your code is using backwards slashes.

Comment: Further to @turbo's comment, use the `Path` API to abstract from platform specific directory separators.

Comment: Even if I do that I get No Such File or Directory error when it is run on a Linux system nor will it even attempt to download.

Comment: Ensure the path exists, use [`Files.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) to check and if not use [`File.mkdirs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) to make it.  It looks like you did something like that in the windows version, not sure what `one`, `two`, and `three` are though.

Comment: Again, It does not work lol, shows no such file or directory. The mkdir commands I used for the window one was just a test. They are unused. Just 3 unused commands that were forgot to be deleted. As I said before is that nomatter what I cannot download a file directly to the root/user home directory. It downloads and extract in the root folder but that is not what I need to access.